# How to use ant exec task to invoke curl and POST a message to rest api

Tags: curl, post, ant, exec, content-type

Created an Ant task to make a curl post request :

```
<target name="invoke-curl" description="Invoke curl using Ant">
    <exec executable="curl">
        <arg value="-kiv" />
        <arg value="-X POST" />
        <arg value="-H 'Accept: application/json'" />
        <arg value="-H 'Content-Type: application/json'" />        
        <arg value="-d" />
        <arg value="&apos;{&quot;username&quot;:&quot;xyz&quot;,&quot;password&quot;:&quot;XYZ&quot;}&apos;" />
        <arg value="https://hostname:8443/rest/api/login" />        
    </exec>
</target>
```

Interestingly the API supports only "Content-Type: application/json". But curl seems to be adding the **"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** in addition to the header sent as a parameter to Curl. The API does not seem to like this and returns "< HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type". It looks like curl is finding the data encoded and hence setting this default header on its own. So is there a way to prevent curl from setting this default "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and just use the header set as a parameter to curl command.

```
User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
Accept: */*
 'Accept: application/json'
 'Content-Type: application/json'
Content-Length: 52
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it was old,  you can try e.g.:

```
<exec executable="curl">
    <arg value="-kiv" />
    <arg value="-X" />
    <arg value="POST"/>
    <arg value="-H" />
    <arg value="Accept: application/json" />
    <arg value="http://localhost:${diagnose.management.port}/manage/shutdown" />
</exec>
```

This will execute as below:
 `curl -kiv -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" "http://localhost:${diagnose.management.port}/manage/shutdown"`

Note that: each arg value seems to be added a double quote in the result if it contains a space.

refer to: https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg

Answer (score 0):

change your code as shown below

```
<target name="invoke-curl" description="Invoke curl using Ant">
        <exec executable="curl">
            <arg value="-kiv" />
            <arg value="-X POST" />
            <arg value="-H" />
            <arg value="Accept: application/json" />
            <arg value="-H" />
            <arg value="Content-Type: application/json" />        
            <arg value="-d" />
            <arg value="&apos;{&quot;username&quot;:&quot;xyz&quot;,&quot;password&quot;:&quot;XYZ&quot;}&apos;" />
            <arg value="https://hostname:8443/rest/api/login" />        
        </exec>
    </target>
```

Comment: more explanation needed

Answer (score 0):

Many platforms don't have curl installed by default.
To be cross platform, a custom ant task would be better. Either use the [HTTP Post task from contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/post_task.html) or write one of your own.